# downloaded html file look incoherent text

Tags: android, html, encode

I have downloaded html files from an android application. They can be read very well when it is opened by the application but on computer it seems incoherent. Also there is a css. If it is needed I can upload it. I'm not experienced in HTML. Is it encoded? If it is, how can be decoded?

All files http://bookfiles.host-ed.me/

one of them includes (all of content copied here)

```
>n"@XQ!@y«à 'ÖíD¤ÂÂş‚w ÚD&3íìª<«´bÏ×wxtcí–ÿeªŞ2ãìÔNi5LXK(èøÄØ7?òœÖ–'M‹—PÆŒªl    Ñ«Â€LhùFééÎ¶Ø®`¬IJbË\fw@¡f“Í^ïXÇÑÚ5¹9#šL[2f‹Mƒ:œ ³’çyv¾r»“0îéùÑhÕ(*ş†3¦ÂŒ$Õ€çñd%îS=«‡4Ìæ¡1I¿¾”Ô+‡;ó«HÍñˆıneİ3|Ët"]Uûj¼tH^şiÖ!(ï7­¡Œ¥v©îCãm3±C‹oRìO‡šø;h¡nï[C¸Õ"HÒêûè3c^¸`+İê¿LLA¶*%Ï<.ö_7óÓ/àÙH˜PSH(²M‘7ÌzÆ$÷öD’ğ ¦Ád´¼3ÿ­5À²©;<ÛP)øs³ pZdÕœˆÜ·x‡zlKSu5¡6kgö@sëKCÓøÚ»°0)'ÊÒÅşxõŸiD²?DUkŞŠFµÇì¯ÅKû~bÆ1­^§'2jéçë
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML is often compressed as [part of the HTTP protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression). I'm not sure how you downloaded the page without decompression (wget does this automatically), but you could try decompressing it with gzip or Deflate (Wikipedia mentions these two as common) if you don't know what the compression system was.